# I want to start programming using a kinect . Should I start with the XBOX 360 version one or the new version 2 of the kinect?

Tags: windows, computer-vision, kinect, kinect-sdk, openkinect

I wish to start programming with the Kinect . I am unsure of which one is recommended for first timers . Also I would like to take into consideration the support online for each version and documentation available

Comment: Off-topic on StackOverflow

Comment: Off-topic, but to answer your question - you'll likely want to use Kinect version 2. It has better specs (higher depth sensor resolution, better skeletal tracking, etc.). Both are well documented, and I would imagine more people are using Kinect v2 online than the original Kinect Xbox 360. Note that Kinect has reached end-of-life and is no longer being manufactured. The new Project Kinect for Azure was recently announced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either are just fine. You could use bot, I should recommend you that Kinect is supported by programming languages as Python,C++ or C# (1 and 3 are easier for a beginner to learn).

In my opinion you should split tasks like the following:

```
           1)Learn some basic programming concepts
           2)Experiment with Kinect
           3)Read about human-computer interaction, image processing concepts
           4)Have fun with the Kinect sensor in addition with the aforementioned
```

Comment: Thanks ! I have some experience with Opencv , so it should be fine